# Android: does Activity onCreate load at app start-up?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, oncreate

I am trying to solve a problem with a RecyclerView list. I'm wondering does the RecyclerView Activity's onCreate method run at app start-up or only when I run the MainActivity method (an Intent) that launches the RecyclerView?  Meaning, does Activity B's (the RecyclerView's) onCreate method run at app start-up or only after Activity A launches Activity B?

Comment: I don't know what your comment is saying...please advise.

Comment: I think after Activity A launches Activity B :D

Comment: Please refer **Activity Lifecycle** http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle to know more detail

Comment: Yes, I've read that before.  I'm trying to understand if all of the activities start together once the app is started or do they start one at time, after one is destroyed and a new one is created.

Comment: What you can do is put a "Log" in each methods (oncreate, onresume, onpause, etc,.) and see how the sequence goes. As for your question, (someone just correct me if I'm mistaken) onCreate of activity B gets called only after activity A call B.

Comment: Ok I will try the Logging, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only activity that is created at startup is one that have

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent_filter>
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml`

So at application startup only activity A (if it have `intent-filter`) will get `onCreate`. Activity B `onCreate` is called when it is created by intent from activity A.